# How can I import text file on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following text files in the same directory with my code:

`Text1.txt`:

```
This is text1
```

`Text2.txt`

```
This is text2
```

I want to make a page where when a user clicks a list, each list connects with a text file and the content of text file will be shown in the console. How do I do it?

[image]

`App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Text1.txt';
import './Text2.txt';



class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Text Lists</h1>
        <div>
          <h2 onClick={this.showTitle}><li>Click this to show text1</li></h2>
          <h2 onClick={this.showTitle}><li>Click this to show text2</li></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using webpack in your implementation, you will need to use `file-loader` to do this.
You can read on how [here](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/). It's pretty simple if you have done the same with `css` or any other style loaders.

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(txt)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          publicPath: 'assets',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Once the loader is setup you should be able to import it like you would a module

`import textfile from './Text1.txt';`