# Unzip a local file in react

Tags: reactjs, unzip

I have a local file in the 'public' directory and am attempting to unzip it with `jszip`:

```
import JSZip from 'jszip';
import myZip from '../public/test.zip';

function App() {
  const zip = new JSZip();

  zip.loadAsync(myZip)
    .then(function (zip) {
      console.log(zip)
    });


   // render function
}
```

but I'm getting the following error: `Error: Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file?`

I am assuming that a) the file is being imported properly and possibly b) that I am misusing the `loadAsync` function.

Comment: Do not assume your file is being imported properly

Comment: Your problem is likely related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62050462/how-can-i-import-text-file-on-react